# Center absolute positioned pseudo element

Tags: css, css-position

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aoyfacd/3/). What I am trying to do is to absolute position the FontAwesome play button on top of the image and in the center. Wondering if anyone has tried this before or has any insight, have tried to do it every way I can think.

Note, I do not have access to the markup on the page I am working on, has to be pure CSS.

```css
.test {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.test:before {
  content: "\f144";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis dicta quae a illo nulla, temporibus in nostrum id quia totam sint veritatis aspernatur vitae, similique labore non voluptate, dolores magnam.
  </div>
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-default">Learn More >></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You’re going to have a major problem if you’re trying to do this responsively. Is the image of a fixed size? The problem is that, since you’re attaching the button to the `div` container, and that’s going to vary in size, then the normal techniques will fail. If, however the image is of a fixed height, then there is a solution.

Comment: @Manngo Agreed, only possible by using javascript with dynamic image height and no markup change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the given markup, and if you know the image ratio up front, you can do like this, where you use it to calculate against the viewport width `vw`, combined with `transform: translate`.

In this case the image ratio factor is 150 / 350 ~ 0.428

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8aoyfacd/5/)

```css
.test {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.test:before {
    content: "\f144";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    top: calc(50vw * 0.428);              /* width * image ratio factor */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis dicta quae a illo nulla, temporibus in nostrum id quia totam sint veritatis aspernatur vitae, similique labore non voluptate, dolores magnam.
  </div>
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-default">Learn More >></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @FlyFishingAllDay Anything for a fly fishing brother :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this!

```
<div class="test">
<div class="image">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<div class="play"></div>
</div>

<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
<div class="description">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis dicta quae a illo nulla, temporibus in nostrum id quia totam sint veritatis aspernatur vitae, similique labore non voluptate, dolores magnam.
</div>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-default">Learn More >></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
.image{
  position:relative;
}
.play::after {
    content: "\f144";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not have access to the markup on the page I am working on, has to be pure CSS. I basically just recreated the issue...

Comment: So, if you know the height of the image, you only have to put top: XXpx to center the play button on the image.

Comment: Also has to be responsive...my bad for failing to mention that. I will try that for desktop main view though.

Comment: I would do it with media queries controlling the size of the image on each size of screen.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Javascript for that, here is an example via jQuery:

- Insert a wrapper and set it to the same height as the banner image.
- Add the fa play icon into that wrapper.
- Put them into jQuery `resize()` function to make it responsive.
- Use CSS flexbox or any other approach to center the icon in the wrapper.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t9825bn/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if (!$('.wrap').length) {
    $('<div class="wrap"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>').prependTo('.test');
  }
  $('.wrap').css('height', $('.test img').height());
});
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis dicta quae a illo nulla, temporibus in nostrum id quia totam sint veritatis aspernatur vitae, similique labore non voluptate, dolores magnam.
  </div>
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-default">Learn More >></a>
</div>
```